# Array larger than specified size in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

When testing an array like this:

```
float test [3] = {1, 2, 3};

cout << "Test size: " << sizeof(test) << endl;
```

The size shown by the print statement is `12`. Similarly, when I made the size `12`, the number of elements in the array was `47`. Isn't this the correct way to specify the size of an array in C++?

Comment: `sizeof()` does not return the # of elements.

Comment: If you have C++ 17, use [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size). `std::cout << std::size(test);`

Comment: I feel like there should be a duplicate somewhere but I just can't find it. Surely someone else has also thought that `sizeof` gives the length of an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sizeof` doesn't return the number of elements in the array, it returns the memory size in bytes. Since your array contains three regular integers, and integers are 4 bytes in size, that's 3 * 4 == 12 bytes.

To get the *length* of the array, you have a few options:

---

#### Option 1

```cpp
int size = sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]);
```

What that does is get the size of the array (which is 12 bytes) then divides that by the size of a single element (which is 4 bytes). Obviously 12 / 4 == 3.

---

#### Option 2

As pointed out by @PaulMcKenzie, if you're able to use C++17 you can use [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size). That makes it very easy because you can just do this:

```cpp
int size = std::size(test);
```

---

#### Option 3 (Not recommended)

```cpp
int size = *(&test + 1) - test;
```

Which is a clever hack using pointers, explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-size-of-array-in-cc-without-using-sizeof-operator/). Will result in undefined behaviour and may break, depending on the compiler and its optimisations.

Comment: I think dereferencing *(&test + 1)* invokes Undefined Behavior, per C standard (there is no float array in that address, after all). Agressive optimizations by compiler might break code like that, even if common sense says it should be fine. Avoid.

Comment: @hyde this is a C++ question - in C++ it is unclear whether the code is UB or not

Comment: @M.M Oh right. But is this really different in C++? No standard handy, but I'd imgine rules about dereferencing pointers are about the same.

Comment: They aren't the same

Comment: Evaluating `&test + 1` is valid in C++, but undefined in C.   Dereferencing it, as in `*(&test + 1)`, gives undefined behaviour in both languages.

Comment: Using `int` can overflow because the expressions return `std::size_t` which can be larger. Using `auto size = ...` is probably safer.

Comment: @Peter Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Galik I would say it's fair to assume the code writer would know what the expected size of the array is.

Comment: @Clonkex - there is no "could" on undefined behaviour.  The behaviour is either undefined (the standard places no requirements or constraints on what happens) or it is not. While code with undefined behaviour might "break" depending on the compiler and its optimisations, that is a *consequence* of the behaviour being undefined, not the cause or definition of undefined behaviour.   Even if the code doesn't "break", the behaviour is still undefined.

Comment: @Peter Not necessarily. For one compiler it might be well defined (as in, specifically documented behaviour), even if it's not defined in the standard. But I get your point so I'll update the post :)

Comment: @Clonkex - There has never been a compiler with documented behaviour of allowing safe dereference of a pointer that points past the end of an object or array.   There are plenty of cases of compilers doing that by accident, but not consistently or reliably  (e.g. the code can work with one version of a particular compiler, then fail when that compiler is updated - or the reverse).

Comment: @Peter My point was, I'm not a C++ expert, let alone a C++ compiler expert. I have absolutely no idea if that's a normal thing to expect from a compiler so I can't possibly know if it _maybe_ results in undefined behaviour or _definitely will_. I can't tell if you're just letting me know (friendly) or if you're calling me a noob for not knowing that (jerk) so I apologise if my response is a little blunt.

Comment: @Clonkex - I was explaining that your description demonstrates a complete misunderstanding of the meaning of undefined behaviour, and your responses have continued to demonstrate the same misunderstanding.  I made no comment about you as an individual.   I'll leave it there.

Comment: @Peter There's have no misunderstanding. Undefined behaviour stops being undefined if it's defined. I don't know much about compilers so I wasn't sure if there might be a compiler that documented safe dereference of a pointer that points past the end of an array. With that assumption, it's only _possible_ that the behaviour is undefined, not guaranteed, depending which compiler you use. However you stated factually that no compiler documents such behaviour, so if your statement is true (which I assume it is) then it _is_ guaranteed to have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Clondex.  You continue to demonstrate your misunderstanding.   Read up on how the C++ standard specifically *defines* the term "undefined".    The C++ standard is the authoritative yardstick on what is undefined, or not, in the context of C++ - because that is a *fundamental purpose* of a standard.  Compiler documentation can only describe what a particular compiler does, but it *cannot* overrule the standard. Because the C++ standard is the yardstick against which *all* compilers (at least those that claim to comply with it) is assessed.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the more efficient way of calculating the number of elements in an array, you could use templates.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
std::size_t GetArrLength(T(&)[Size]) { return Size; }
```

If we call it as such:

```
float test[3] = {1,2,3};
GetArrLength(test);
```

The compiler will try to deduce the template parameters. For the parameter type to match what you're passing, T must be float and size must be 3 (making the parameter a reference to an array of 3 floats).

Comment: More efficient than what, and in what way? It'd be good if you could elaborate. Also it might be worth explaining in a more ELI5 fashion given the OP is probably new to C++ and templates are confusing to newbies (especially for clever uses like this).

Comment: You are basically reimplementing `std::size()`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl What if you dont have C++ 17 supported compiler. BTW i didn't know that this is what std::size is.

Answer (score 3):

You must use following way to get the actual size of array you requires.

```
 int size = sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);
```

`sizeof()` actually [returns no. of bytes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof). So, you get the no. of bytes in your array object. To get actually the no. of elements, we need to divide it by the size of an element there. For example, here `sizeof(float)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the single element size to get the array size.

```
int sz = sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]);
cout << "test size: " << sz << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
size_t n = sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]);
```

`size`_t is a type **guaranteed** to hold any array index, so use `size_t`.

Comment: You should probably read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so you know how the formatting works :P

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has a type trait for this purpose.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float test [3] = {1, 2, 3};

    std::cout 
        << std::extent<decltype(test)>::value 
        << '\n';
}
```